# Elasticsearch query on other ID field

Tags: exception, elasticsearch

how to get match field with a string that contains "_id" in its field name.

like so:
`{"query": "match" : {"extra_id": "1111_222"} }`

it shows me **"number_format_exception"** error.

But when I change field name to something like "extra" it works fine.

This is my complete request body:

```
GET /latest/extra_data/_search?size=2000
{
    "query": {
       "match": {
          "extra_id": "55502323230_81015572923293301509"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have documents in which the value of `extra_id` was a number without an underscore in it ? If yes, the mapping for that field is probably a numeric type (`integer`, `long`, etc) and `"1111_222"` cannot be coerced to a number, hence the number format exception you get.

Comment: @Val I save all its data as TEXT. but before saving I should check its existence which shows this error. So I should use `mapping`?

Comment: Can you show what you get when running this: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index`?

Comment: @Val I've updated my post and added my complete `GET` request.

Comment: That's not the request I asked for. Please check my previous comment again. I'd like to see your mapping.

Comment: @Val sorry, this is the result `"text_id":{"type":"long"}`

Comment: the issue was with your `extra_id` field, not `text_id`, or was it a typo?

Comment: @Val oops I'm so sorry man, it was my mistake. that's it: `"extra_id":{"type":"long"}`

Comment: Ok since `extra_id` is of type long you cannot try to match a string that cannot be coerced to a long. You need to wipe your index and change the type of that field to `string` instead. Then you'll be able to run that query.